# i2c instead of mdio, marvell phy driver

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am trying to run marvell phy linux driver on my custom board.
The driver uses mdio interface, but my board has i2c.

I replaced phy_read()/phy_write() in marvell.c file by i2c read/write functions. It doesn't work. probe function doesn't called, phy subsystem uses mdio for detecting marvell, and cannot detect it.

How can I use i2c in phy linux sysbsystem?

Comment: You need to have a phy driver which communicates via i2c. I think it might be already in the kernel

Comment: I'm looking for it but can't find it. https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/phy.html  says "Different devices use different busses (though some share common interfaces). In order to take advantage of the PAL, each bus interface needs to be registered as a distinct device". Is it mean, I have to implement my own bus module, for i2c?

Comment: It's not a complete driver, more of a sub-module, but "drivers/net/phy/mdio-i2c.c" provides the `mdio_i2c_alloc` function to create a bridge to an mdio (mii) bus over I2C. The SFP driver ("drivers/net/phy/sfp.c") uses it.

Comment: It should be noted that if your PHY chip or module expects to talk over an MDIO bus, you cannot just connect it to an I2C bus and expect it to work. The wire protocols are different.

Comment: "It's not a complete driver, more of a sub-module, but "drivers/net/phy/mdio-i2c.c" provides the mdio_i2c_alloc function to create a bridge to an mdio (mii) bus over I2C." I have seen it, mdio_alloc should call from probe, but probe doesn't called.

Answer (score 1):

I decided it with mdio-i2c.c module and  wrote my own platform driver. 
In my driver probe:

```
new_bus = mdio_i2c_alloc(&pdev->dev, i2c);   /* create bridge */
if (!new_bus){
    return -ENOMEM;
}
new_bus->name = "marvell mdio i2c bus";
new_bus->parent = &pdev->dev;
err = of_mdiobus_register(new_bus, pdev->dev.of_node);
```

dts:

```
    mdio_i2c{
        compatible = "marvell,i2c-mdio";
        i2c-bus = <&i2c_0>;
        ethphy1: ethernet-phy@1f {
            reg = <0x1f>;
        };
    };
```

It's work.
There is one caveat. A marvell88e1111 has 0x5f i2c address. This address is unacceptable for mdio. I set address 0x1f. The mdio-i2c.c module corrects it

```
static unsigned int i2c_mii_phy_addr(int phy_id)
{
    return phy_id + 0x40;
}
```